# Path caused incorrect display in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, path

I am new to cakephp. This problem is my key development issue. I was trying to avoid asking this question on stack overflow because i have past experience of marks being deducted for noob questions. I researched solution for almost two days now on google, however, all the solutions are either not really useful or so unclear to a newbie like me. I need professionals from stack overflow to help me.

Basically, i installed xampp on mac, the path to my xampp in `httpd.conf` is

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
```

now i created a subfolder in `htdocs` named as `cake`, the installed cakephp in it. cakephp is working, but the problem is the **image files and css are not displaying** . I searched online and many suggested solution to change `.htaccess` . Here are my three `.htaccess` changes

**.htaccess under cake**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cake/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess under cake>app**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cake/app/
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess under cake>app>webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cake/app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However image and css is still not working. Please help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Apache's mod_rewrite?

Have you allowed individual folders to override server settings with .htaccess?

In your system conf file, make sure you have the following:

```
AllowOverride All
```

In the directory directive that covers your webroot.

Comment: Hi yes done that, mod_rewrite is on, and allow override all are done